# How- XLST Transformation

Tags: xml-parsing, transform, xslt-2.0

Just wanted to ask on how to get the author names in the given xml sample below and put an attribut of eq="yes". EQ means Equal Contributors.

This is the XML.

```
<ArticleFootnote Type="Misc">
<Para>John Doe and Jane Doe are equal contributors.</Para>
</ArticleFootnote>
```

This should be the output in other form of XML.

```
<AuthorGroups>
<Authors eq="yes">John Doe</Authors>
<Authors eq="yes">Jane Doe</Authors>
</AuthorGroups>
```

Assuming that JOhn Doe and Jane Doe are already defined in the list of authors but after the transformation, author tag should have the attribute eq="yes". Please help as I don't know much writing in xlst.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT isn't a good tool (as we know there is no good tool at all) for parsing natural language. Please, re-tag the question as `natural-language-parsing`.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information here to give you a clear answer.

If you have a list of authors, you could use fn:match() on each author's name in turn, maybe after changing space to \s+ in the pattern.

I normally use Perl to do this sort of thing, though, being careful not to disrupt the tagging structure.

In any case you'll either need to process the text a word at a time, probably recursively to find the longest match in cases where one name is just "John" and another is "John Doe". Watch that you don't add markup to names you've already processed.

In the case that the text really always says exactly what you have there, but with different names, though, you could have a template to match ArticleFootnote/Para[contains(., 'are equal contrubutors')] and either use substring() and substring-before() or the XSLT 2 pattern matching.

Comment: How do I implement this in my XSLT? Please help.